# Support Plane Confusion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

(Lieb and Loss Analysis pg. 44)

> “A support plane  to a graph of a function $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ at a point $x\in K$ is a plane (in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) that touches the graph at $(x,f(x))$ and that nowhere lies above the graph ... $f$ convex on $K$... at least one support plane at each point of thr interior of $K$. Thus, there exists a vector $V\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (which depends on $x$) such that 
>   $$f(y)\ge f(x)+V\cdot (y-x)$$
>   for all $y\in K$.”

In the line, “and that nowhere lies above the graph” what does he mean? Does he mean that $f=\infty$ at the point where the plane intersects the its graph? Also, how can we conclude $f(y)\ge f(x)+V\cdot (y-x)$
for all $y\in K$?

Comment: Why would it mean $f = \infty$ at the point where the plane meets the graph of $f$?

Comment: The plane does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if $x \in K$ and $(x,y)$ belongs to the support plane then $y \leq f(x)$.

For example, the x-y plane $\{(x,y,0) \mid x, y \in \mathbb R \}$ is a support plane for the graph of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ at the point $(0,0)$.

To answer the follow-up question, I think it will be more clear to slightly change notation. A support plane $W$ to the graph of $f$ at a point $x_0$ must be non-vertical, so there exists a vector $V$ and a scalar $b$ such that $W$ is the graph of the equation $y = V \cdot (x - x_0) + b$. Note that $W$ touches the graph of $f$ at $(x_0,f(x_0))$, which implies that $$f(x_0)= b.$$ Thus, $W$ is the graph of $y = V\cdot (x - x_0) + f(x_0)$. It follows that
$$ f(x) \geq V\cdot (x - x_0) + f(x_0)$$ for all $x$ in $K$.

Comment: So, the plane meets the graph when $f=\infty$?

Comment: Also, how do you obtain $f(y)\ge f(x) + V\cdot (y-x)$